# wsl2 ip mismatches wsl2 adapter?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

This has never happened but suddenly I'm not able to access server running on localhost in wsl2.

Looking deeper I see that IPs are different

```
wsl hostname -I
192.168.40.75

ipconfig
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::491e:.......
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.65
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   .......
```

What caused it and how can I prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing with the IP addresses is normal.  The `wsl hostname -I` is giving you the address of the virtual NIC *inside* WSL, while `ipconfig` is showing you the Windows side of that connection.

`wsl ip route show` should show that the default route out from the WSL instance is that Windows IP.

As for not being able to access a WSL service via Windows `localhost`, that's likely due to a bug/issue where WSL loses the localhost forwarding when Windows is hibernated.  And while you might not think you've hibernated recently, a normal Windows shutdown actually results in a pseudo-hibernate due to the "Fast Startup" feature in Windows, which is enabled by default.

Solution is usually (hopefully) simply to exit your WSL instance, do a `wsl --shutdown`, and start WSL back up again.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455770/11810933) for more details.

Comment: i tried everything, and in end i updated windows to dev release version which fixed it.

Comment: Well, at least now you can use WSLg!  I'd love to try it out, but I'm not ready to move my production machine over to Insider just yet.

Comment: definitely!, the regular version had been working fine for a year. it just stopped working. I think something to do me trying to open firewall which worked but disconnected something that later resulted in this. there was a fix but it required restarting computer every time.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64057835/1319799